# Most elegant way to join a Map to a String in Java 8

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I love [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), and I'll continue to use Guava a lot. But, where it makes sense, I try to use the "new stuff" in *Java 8* instead.

**"Problem"**

Lets say I want to join url attributes in a `String`. In *Guava* I would do it like this:

```
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
attributes.put("a", "1");
attributes.put("b", "2");
attributes.put("c", "3");

// Guava way
String result = Joiner.on("&").withKeyValueSeparator("=").join(attributes);
```

Where the `result` is `a=1&b=2&c=3`.

**Question**

What is the most elegant way to do this in *Java 8* (without any 3rd party libraries)?

Comment: "using only Java 8" is pretty vague, since anything you can do in Java 7 can also be done in Java 8.

Comment: What is meant is using Java 8, without any libraries. Libraries would defeat the purpose if this exercise. Java 8 also comes with some nice apis, and syntax changes, that Java 7 doesn't have. Which opens up for some elegant programming.

Comment: A side note: if you wish to create a URL query string, you're doing this in the wrong way as you need to escape special characters which may appear in key names or values.

Comment: Good point @TagirValeev.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can grab the stream of the map's entry set, then map each entry to the string representation you want, joining them in a single string using [`Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-).

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

String s = attributes.entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .map(e -> e.getKey()+"="+e.getValue())
                     .collect(joining("&"));
```

But since the entry's `toString()` already output its content in the format `key=value`, you can call its `toString` method directly:

```
String s = attributes.entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .map(Object::toString)
                     .collect(joining("&"));
```

Comment: Note that while `HashMap` entries are actually printed in `key=value` format, this is never specified, thus it's a bad practice to rely on this fact.

Comment: That is why I provided the first alternative.

Answer (score 3):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {


        HashMap<String,Integer> newPhoneBook = new HashMap(){{
            putIfAbsent("Arpan",80186787);
            putIfAbsent("Sanjay",80186788);
            putIfAbsent("Kiran",80186789);
            putIfAbsent("Pranjay",80186790);
            putIfAbsent("Jaiparkash",80186791);
            putIfAbsent("Maya",80186792);
            putIfAbsent("Rythem",80186793);
            putIfAbsent("Preeti",80186794);

        }};


        /**Compining Key and Value pairs and then separate each pair by some delimiter and the add prefix and Suffix*/
        String keyValueCombinedString = newPhoneBook.entrySet().stream().
                // you can improve the performance by avoiding "+"
                // "map(entrySet -> "%s:%s".formatted(entrySet.getKey(), entrySet.getValue())."
                map(entrySet -> entrySet.getKey() + ":"+ entrySet.getValue()).
                collect(Collectors.joining("," , "[","]"));
        System.out.println(keyValueCombinedString);

        /**
         *  OUTPUT : [Kiran:80186789,Arpan:80186787,Pranjay:80186790,Jaiparkash:80186791,Maya:80186792,Sanjay:80186788,Preeti:80186794,Rythem:80186793]
         *
         * */


        String keyValueCombinedString1 = newPhoneBook.entrySet().stream().
                map(Objects::toString).
                collect(Collectors.joining("," , "[","]"));
        System.out.println(keyValueCombinedString1);

        /**
         * Objects::toString method concate key and value pairs by =
         * OUTPUT : [Kiran=80186789,Arpan=80186787,Pranjay=80186790,Jaiparkash=80186791,Maya=80186792,Sanjay=80186788,Preeti=80186794,Rythem=80186793]
         * */

    }

> Blockquote
```